# Horizontal DIVs with text wrapping

Tags: css

I have 4 DIVs positioned horizontally next to each other.

**DIV #1** has a fixed width, but also needs to be stretched to the full height of the container DIV (this works fine already).

**DIV #2** has a fixed with but does not need to be stretched in its height (this also works fine already).

**DIV #3** contains text. This text shall be wrapped. Based on the length of the text (and the height of DIV #3), also the height of the container DIV shall increase. **This does NOT work yet**.

**DIV #4** contains some controls. They shall be right-aligned and can overlay the text (this works fine already).

Any ideas?

This is my code:

```css
.container {
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.fullheight {
  width: 30px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.fixed {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: violet;
  width: 50px;
  color: white;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.dynamic {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  background: orange;
  margin: 2px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 2px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fullheight">
      #1
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
      #2
    </div>
    <div class="dynamic">
      #3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
      #4
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deb_ugger/8gyH8/36/)

Comment: What happens when you set a width (or a max-width) on div #3?

Comment: Explane it like i'm five... It don't get the probrem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this how you want it to look like?

```css
.container {
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

.fullheight {
  width: 30px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.fixed {
  background-color: violet;
  width: 50px;
  color: white;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.dynamic {
  overflow: auto;
  background: orange;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-left: -110px;
  /*max-height: 100px;    if you want this to scroll at some point */
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 2px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fullheight">
      #1
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
      #2
    </div>
    <div class="dynamic">
      #3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
      #4
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly how it should look like!

Comment: Hi! Any ideas how to get rid of the elements margin on the right side? Just use your browsers dev.tools and select the orange .dynamic DIV. It shows a margin on the right side.

Comment: @Stephan Do you mean the orange'd colored shadow like overflow when view using google's inspect/dev.tools ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */ (remove)
}
```

Because if you use white-space: nowrap; it will continue on the same line until a `<br>` is noticed.

Default is `white-space: normal;` or just leave it away.

[Learn more about white-space on W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

**Edit:**

Leave the container:

```
.dynamic {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  background: orange;
  margin: 2px;
  white-space: normal; /* add to overrule parent property*/
  width: calc(100% - 120px); /*use of calc() to set to maximum width minus what is already been used.*/
}
```

[Can i use calc()?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

[Specificity, how to overrule and why a style is overruled on htmldog](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/)

***Working example:***

```css
.container {
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

.fullheight {
  width: 30px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.fixed {
  background-color: violet;
  width: 50px;
  color: white;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.dynamic {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  background: orange;
  margin: 2px;
  white-space: normal;
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 2px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fullheight">
      #1
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
      #2
    </div>
    <div class="dynamic">
      #3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
      #4
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: OP says: _I have 4 DIVs positioned horizontally next to each other._, so when you make that change they are not horizontal next to each other anymore.

Comment: O, sorry a minute. didn't read your post all to well. Give a minute ;-)

Comment: Thanks! This is also what I was looking for. Didn't know about the "calc" method yet!

Comment: @Stephan feel free to ask me more if you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

Think you want somethig like:

```
.container {
background-color: black;
min-height: 55px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
clear: both;
//white-space: nowrap;
}

.fullheight {
 width: 30px;
 background: green;
 color: white;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.fixed {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 background-color: violet;
 width: 50px;
 color: white;
 margin: 2px;
 margin-left: 35px;
}

.dynamic {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: calc(100% - 100px); //Adjust the size of your dynamic div here
 background: orange;
 margin: 2px;
}

.overlay {
 position: absolute;
 margin: 2px;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background: red;
```

}

an the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gyH8/37/)